# Can 12v dc circuit spark and start a fire?

Tags: led, batteries, dc, safety

I'm new to electronics and electricity. I have the following scenario:

I am wiring a LED light switch and mounting it into wooden cladding. My concern is, can the wires spark unexpectedly and start a fire?

We are talking about 12V DC, with three, 2W LEDs. The circuit is properly fused.

[image: the switch]

Comment: Looks like you crammed that poor LED in there until it almost broke

Comment: @laptop2d Let's assume it's the lens causing the distortion... I wouldn't worry about it starting fire unless working in some flammable gas filled space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, 12V can certainly cause sparks if there is a connection that is opening and/or closing.  However, I expect you are safe:

1. Since you are fused, any high-current short should blow the fuse before anything bad happens.
2. Your 12V power supply likely has some reasonable current limit, and
3. It's hard to ignite wood with sparks.

If you were around a flammable gas or liquid, however, any sparks could be devastating.

Once I was stranded at night (with my malfunctioning car) on a road in the wilderness.  I had some camping gear with me, but no method to light my cookstove. I used jumper cables from the car's 12V battery to create sparks and light the stove.

I don't recommend this!  It took a while for the hair on my forearms to grow back :)

---

P.S. Make sure you note @Trevor's important point about strain relief in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the connections are sound and no extraneous bits of wire etc. are around it "should" be safe.

However, when burying things like this it is prudent to ensure that no stress can be exerted on the connections, either as part of the install, or later. As such you need to relieve those cable turns and add appropriate cable tie downs to make sure nobody can pull on the cable later breaking the integrity of the connections.

**Ultimately, there is ALWAYS a risk of fire, so nobody on here will stand by a blank "Yes, it's fine and won't start a fire!" statement.**

However, as a side note, your design may not be a great idea anyway. If at some point that switch fails you will need to replace it. I have a feeling you do not want to rip the trim out of the wall to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you bring them close together enough, or if you introduce a liquid, or if you connect them to a high voltage or something. But as long as you properly terminate or insert them, with no loose strands or nicks or cuts, you should be fine.